# Tree diagram and probability

Tags: probability

[image]

The correct answer is shown to be 0.168, but I can't figure out why.

I got the answer 0.8 $\cdot$ 0.2=0.160 because the question is asking what is the probability of Jen's father drove her to class given that Jen makes it on time.

what am I missing here ?

Thank you!

Comment: $Pr(B'\mid F)$ is not the same thing as $Pr(B'\cap F)$.  The calculation $0.8\cdot 0.2$ would represent the calculation $Pr(B'\cap F)=Pr(B')\cdot Pr(F\mid B')=0.2\cdot 0.8$, i.e. this is the calculation for that her father drove her *and* she made it on time (*the key difference being the word 'and' rather than the word 'given'*).  Rather... you should be applying Bayes' Theorem here.

Comment: $Pr(B'\mid F)=\dfrac{Pr(B'\cap F)}{Pr(F)}=\dfrac{Pr(B')\cdot Pr(F\mid B')}{Pr(B)Pr(F\mid B)+Pr(B')Pr(F\mid B')} = \dots$

Comment: ah so Bayes' Theorem is what I missed, thank you!

Comment: The formula is: $P(\text{Father drove given Jen made})=\frac{P(\text{Father drove and Jen made})}{P(\text{Jen made})}=\frac{0.2\cdot 0.8}{0.2\cdot 0.8+0.8\cdot 0.99}=0.168$.